# Securing the Dropbox access token

Tags: android, security, xamarin, dropbox

So I am using Xamarin Android to make a dropbox app which is to be used by the clients of the company (and will not be published on the playstore). Since all its users use the same dropbox account, the access token of the app is hardcoded in the source code like this:

```
var dbx = new DropboxClient("abc_token_xyz")
```

I have a feeling that this is not the best approach since if anyone gets their hands on the apk, they can decompile the app and see the token.

My question is that what is the best way to secure the token? Or should i even use this approach?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a violation of DropBox's terms of service. Better check with them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API was designed with the intention that each user would link their own Dropbox account, in order to interact with their own files. However, it is technically possible to connect to just one account, as you've shown.

The problem is, as already discussed, that the access token can be extracted from the app. This is a more fundamental problem, beyond just the Dropbox API. That is, **client-side apps can't keep secrets**. While there are various attempts you can take to make it more difficult to extract the token, you can't make it impossible.

For that reason, this approach is very much not recommended. Once someone has the access token, they can use it to bypass any access controls you attempted to enforce, or even revoke the access token itself, breaking your app.

To somewhat address your first question though, you can:

- obfuscate the token in your code, so that it's not a simple string when the app is inspected. I'm sure there are already good resources for obfuscation in Java available. Note that it can be un-obfuscated though.
- encrypt the access token. Note that the encryption key would also need to be available to the app though, so it could be extracted as well, in order to decrypt the access token.

Further, both of these techniques won't protect against someone performing a man-in-the-middle attack on the device (by installing a trusted certificate on the device) and inspecting the API calls from the app itself to see the token.

Comment: Isn't it common for developers to use Dropbox as a datastore to their apps? Like TapJet (http://tapjet.co) does. Do you think they use a method like this?

Answer (score 1):

An access token should be unique to a device, not only to a user. **Individual device tokens are required to individually revoke access**, which is something you have to consider: what if the device gets lost / stolen? What if the user of the device sells the device / the device is replaced?

Rolling out a new version on all devices for every time a device is lost/stolen/transferred/decommissioned is really nothing you want to do.

---

This answer is valid independently of the service the token is for (and I have no idea of Dropbox' specifics). **It might be a bad idea to use the same Dropbox account for every user at all** (for legal and / or security reasons). You should for example make sure that a token alone is not sufficient to change the password or affect other tokens, or your security is void if a device is lost, even if you have different tokens per device. Also, I have no idea if what you propose violates their ToS.

Comment: I didn't thought of that... thanks. But according to my requirements, the data accumulated from all the devices needs to be centralized on the same dropbox account so separate accounts is not an option.